# Alternative to Appium inspector or app inspector to view mobile elements in iOS

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I like to find out if there are alternative mobile viewers for elements for iOS as I am not getting Appium Inspector or app inspector working.

Please let me know if you know of other alternatives that can view iOS elements.

Comment: That's strange that Appium inspector is not working for you. Can you share what error you get in Appium inspector and what capabilities you passed in it? BTW there is no need to find alternative when Appium inspector is doing great job. So rather finding alternative, find what is causing problem in Appium inspector.

Comment: You could also run the appium doctor if you have not already. You can install a command line version here https://github.com/appium/appium-doctor

Comment: Wasoq Bhamia - The appium inspector crash when i click on the element in app. I have not been able to find a work around for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Xcode Accessibility Inspector.

To open it: Xcode/Open Developer Tool/Accessibility Inspector

Comment: hi rcarba, it does not help. I am looking for element id like those given in appium inspector. Accessibility Inspector does not give this output etc //XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='title']

Answer (score 0):

Check if its a debug/developer signed build and you have the application ipa and other capabilities mentioned correctly to inspect through Appium. If this is not happening, the automation script won't be running as well. You can share the capabilities and the error you are facing, so look into the problem in a better way. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh P. This is a released signed build . I manage to launch it in Appium Inspector (the build on my iPhone). It is only when I click the elements , the appium inspector crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to prevent the Appium Inspector from crashing - basically I should call the Appium Inspector directly instead of through my script. Hence it no longer crash.